# Is there any way to create a disk image where its Finder window will not display the status bar or tab bar?

Tags: finder, dmg, disk-image

I'm trying to create a disk image for distributing an application, where it automatically opens a Finder window in icon view with a custom background. (The sort we see used for many applications.)

However, while it is possible to specify that its Finder window should be in icon view, not show the preview pane, and various other view related properties like that, so far I haven't found a way to specify that the tab bar and status bar should be hidden as well. It seems like those settings don't apply on a folder-by-folder basis, but rather Finder will open new Finder windows using whichever state was chosen last, regardless of the Finder window it applied to. If this is the case, then there would be no way to do what I want.

Am I correct? Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: Fairly certain you are correct.  Showing the Status bar or Tab bar is an all or nothing Finder preference global across all Finder windows.  I've turned both on and I cannot find a single DMG that is able to override it.  By default they are turned off, many users do not turn those options on.